# How do I add variable to grouped_collection_select group_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionview

**Works**

```
 grouped_collection_select(:event, :id, EventGroup.all, 'events', :name, :id, :name)
```

**NoMethodError**

```
 grouped_collection_select(:event, :id, EventGroup.all, 'events(item)', :name, :id, :name)
```

Is there a way to include a variable in the group_method?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work
     grouped_collection_select(:event, :id, EventGroup.all, "events, #{item}", :name, :id, :name)

This method uses EventGroup.all.send to invoke the method from the string.

Comment: Uhh, right, arg fall into first argument of Object.send, you should pass *array to activeview, but it will splat earlier than you need, so I think it's rather impossible. Only by modifying ruby's internal_send() function.

Comment: I'll probably end up setting up my own Hash and do something with [grouped_options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select)